# Postgresql Upgrade from 11 to 12 fails due to "type abstime does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, pg-upgrade

I'm running an old `postgresql` database that was originally installed as v9.6 and I'm progressively upgrading it from one version to the next until I can get it up to date with version 13.3.  The upgrades from 9.6 to 10, and 10 to 11 were successful.  However when I try to upgrade to version 12 I get the following error:

```
bash-4.4$ tail pg_upgrade_dump_16421.log
pg_restore: creating TYPE "public.gtrgm"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.Seqnextval("abstime")"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 662; 1255 16425 FUNCTION Seqnextval("abstime") effective
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  type abstime does not exist
Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "public"."Seqnextval"("abstime") RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE "sql"
    AS $$select setval('units_id_seq', (select max(id) from units)+1) from units limit 1;$$;
```

Here are the steps that I've taken from 11 to 12 to get to where I am right now:

B) Upgrade to PostgreSQL 12

2. Update packages and install postgres

   ```
   sudo yum update
   sudo yum install postgresql12
   ```
3. Stop the postgresql services

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop postgresql-11.service
   sudo systemctl stop postgresql-12.service
   ```
4. Log in as the `postgres` user again

   ```
   sudo su postgres
   ```
5. Change to the home directory

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
6. Migrate the data

   ```
   /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-11/bin --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-12/bin --old-options '-c config_file=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf' --new-options '-c config_file=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql.conf'
   ```
7. Switch to regular user

   ```
    exit
   ```
8. Swap the ports the old and new postgres versions.

   ```
    sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql.conf
    _change port to 5432_
    sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf
    _change port to 5433_
   ```
9. Start the postgresql service

   ```
    sudo systemctl start postgresql-12.service
   ```
10. Log in as postgres user

    ```
    sudo su postgres
    cd ~
    ```
11. Check your new postgres version

    ```
    psql -c "SELECT version();"
    ```
12. Run the generated new cluster script

    ```
     ./analyze_new_cluster.sh
    ```
13. Return as a normal (default user) user and cleanup up the old version's mess

    ```
    exit
    sudo yum remove postgresql11
    sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/11/
    sudo su postgres
    cd ~
    ./delete_old_cluster.sh
    ```

I know for sure that the `abstime` datatype has been removed in `postgresql` 12.  Does anyone here know how to resolve this issue so I can continue with my upgrades?  Please let me know, thanks!  Also if you have any questions, I'm all ears.

Comment: The only way I can think of is in the Postgres 11 instance find and change the `abstime` occurrences to something else. To do so it might be useful to do a `pg_dump -s` to get only the schema definitions and search that for `abstime`.

Comment: Seems you have a user-defined function called `"public"."Seqnextval"` (as per the error output `Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "public"."Seqnextval"("abstime")...`.  I think the best option is to drop the function before using `pg_upgrade`.  After upgrade, you can re-write/re-define the function to work with v. 12

Comment: From what I see in error message: `abstime` argument is not used inside function. You can substitute it with even `anyelement`. But it's possible that there are other functions exists that use `abstime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's possible to do with function "Seqnextval"

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "public"."Seqnextval"("abstime") 
RETURNS bigint
LANGUAGE "sql"
AS $$
select setval('units_id_seq', (select max(id) from units)+1) from units limit 1;
$$;
```

Note that argument of type `abstime` is never used in function.

I suppose it must be safe to change it to:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "public"."Seqnextval"(anyelement)
```

then rerun upgrade process.

## What must be possible to do with `abstime` in general

It could be possible there are other functions that use `abstime`.

Look for other functions:

```sql
WITH funcs AS (
SELECT 
        P.proname,
        p.pronamespace::regnamespace::text AS func_schema,
        obj_description(p.oid),
        pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args,                
        pg_get_function_result(p.oid) AS rettype
    FROM 
        pg_proc P
)
SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        funcs
    WHERE
        (args ~~ '%abstime%'
            OR rettype = 'abstime'
        )
        AND func_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
```

Other tables/views:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema."columns" 
WHERE
    data_type = 'abstime'
    AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
```

If there are no other functions and relations - you're lucky.

Otherwise:

- inspect each function/relation
- decide how to modify them or delegate it to someone other
- change them
- restart upgrade process

Comment: So I ran `DROP FUNCTION "public"."Seqnextval"("abstime")` in `postgres` 11 and that worked, however when I reran the `postgres` 12 upgrade it runs into the same exact problem.  Any idea how to prevent this problem from reoccurring?

Comment: Turns out I was dropping as the wrong user, problem solved!